# Sending file from server to client (python)

Tags: python, client-server, file-transfer

I'm currently writing a server-client application that need to transfer some file to work. 
I'm using this method:

**client:**

```
file_to_send = raw_input(">") 

try:
    f = open("./sent_files/" + file_to_send, "rb")
except IOError, e:
    print ">error: ", e
    break

data = xmlrpclib.Binary(f.read())

if s.receive_file(file_to_send, data):
    print ">file correctly sent"
```

**server:**

```
def receive_file(self, name, arg):                                        
    with open("./sampletest/"+name, "wb") as handle: 
        handle.write(arg.data)
```

But how can I do the opposite (I mean sending a file from the server to the client) ?

Comment: It seems that the client and server are running on the same machine, and you just call server's function in client code.

Answer (score 7):

Just write a function on the *server* like this:

```
def send_file(self, name):
  with open('./sampletest/' + name, 'rb') as handle:
    return handle.read()
```

and call this on the *client*:

```
data = send_file(fileName)
with open('./received_files/' + fileName, 'wb') as handle:
  handle.write(data)
```